# Calculate Distance Formula while using a Scale

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, formula

I am trying to calculate a distance based upon the scale my users draws in.

My user can snap to other points in the game by drawing a line on a grid.

- The grid is a numerical value that they can select 8, 16, 24, or 32.
- The scale can be changed by the user selecting a whole number (1-10) and fraction number (0, 0.5,  0.75, or 0.125).
- The user can select between showing the distance in Metric or Empirical units.

I am having difficulty spitting out the distance once the scale is changed.

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong in my math?

```
- (double) distanceFormula : (float) x1 : (float) y1 : (float) x2 : (float) y2 {
    // 1 meter * 3.280839895 feet => feet
    // 1 foot * 1 meter/3.280839895 feet => meter

    /* Use Pythagora's theorem to calculate distance */
    double dx = (x2-x1);
    double dy = (y2-y1);
    double dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    NSLog(@"Raw Distance %f", dist) ;
    return dist;
}


- (NSString *) returnDistanceAsString : (double) distance {

    NSString * string;
    double d = distance / [self returnGridSize];
    double scale = [self returnScaleWhole] + [self returnScaleSub];

    if ([self returnUseMetric]) {
        //METRIC
        int tempCentim  = (d * kCMConst) / 2;

        if  (tempCentim < 1) {
            string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d mm", tempCentim];
        } else if (tempCentim > 1) {
            string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d mm", tempCentim];
        } else if (tempCentim > 100) {
            //eventually going to add cm mm 
        }

    } else {
        //EMPERICAL
        int RL = d * scale;
        int feet = RL / 12.0;
        int inches = (int)RL % 12;
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i' %i\"", feet, inches];
    }

    return string;
}
```

Comment: Tip: use `hypot(x, y)` from `<math.h>` instead of `sqrt(x * x + y * y)`.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not familiar with Objective-C; what's the advantage of using `hypot(x, y)` in lieu of `sqrt(x*x + y*x)`?

Comment: @andand Readability and precision. (And it's just plain C.)

Comment: I would expect that the two scale values you have now added would be multiplied together. Also no scale is applied for metric.

Answer (score 0):

The main questionable thing I noticed is that, in metric, you're neglecting to multiply by scale, but you are multiplying by kCMConst/2.  You don't explain what kCMConst is, but it seems unlikely to be a value that needs to be divided by 2.